# How to materialize form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, frontend, materialize

So I implemented Materialize css with my Rails app. I already had Bootstrap installed.

Basically I want to have Materialize form components within the app. I have struggles figuring out how to actually create a materialize form in Rails that submits details from the form. I see that components are showing.

How can I implement materialize form components within this form?
In my Devise, edit form,  the form looks like this:

```
 <div class="panel-body">
          <%= form_for resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), layout: :horizontal do |f| %>
            <!-- = devise_error_messages!
            -->
            <div><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %></div>

            <div><%= f.label :last_name %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: true %></div>

            <div><%= f.label :gender %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :gender, autofocus: true %></div>

            <div><%= f.label :age_range %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :age_range, autofocus: true %></div>


            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
            <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
              <p>
                Currently waiting confirmation for: 
                <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %>
              </p>
            <% end %>
            <%= f.password_field :current_password %>
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>

            <%= f.submit "Update" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Which materialize CSS library are you using? Are you using correct CSS classes and wrapper HTML elements for your form inputs as it is required by your materialize CSS lib?

Answer (score 1):

You can use MaterilizeCSS Input field classes for your input fields like this.

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
  <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s6">
  <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: true %>
</div>
```

Like this you can achieve MaterializeCSS style.

Answer (score 0):

Materialize-CSS Component forms are text inputs, more specifically input fields from the docs:
https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html

Example implementation:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row center sign-up-form">
    <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
      <div class="card-panel">
        <h3 class="header">Sign up!</h3>
        <div class="row">
          <%= form_for(@student, html: {class: "col s12"}) do |f| %>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Enter your full name", autofocus: true %>
                <%= f.label :name %>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Enter your email address" %>
                <%= f.label :email %>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn orange waves-effect waves-light right" %>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your gemfile

```
gem 'materialize-form'
```

and follow [these instructions](https://github.com/jamesfwz/materialize-form).